# Can not get media templates working using styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am fairly new to styled-components, and I am trying to get media templates working in my react app. It was created using '[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)'
I followed the code posted in styled-components documentation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const sizes = {
    desktop: 992,
    tablet: 768,
    phone: 376
}

// Iterate through the sizes and create a media template
const media = Object.keys(sizes).reduce((acc, label) => {
    acc[label] = (...args) => css`
         @media (max-width: ${sizes[label] / 16}em) {
            ${css(...args)}
         }
    `

    return acc
}, {})

const Content = styled.div`
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    background: papayawhip;

/* Now we have our methods on media and can use them instead of raw 
queries */
    ${media.desktop`background: dodgerblue;`}
    ${media.tablet`background: mediumseagreen;`}
    ${media.phone`background: palevioletred;`}
`;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          header goes here!!!
        </div>
        <Content/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Nonetheless, I get the following error:

Line 14:  'css' is not defined  no-undef

Line 16:  'css' is not defined  no-undef

line 14 is the following: acc[label] = (...args) => css`

What's wrong with that line?
The link to the piece of code where I got this code is [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#media-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry you're running into troubles. The only thing you need to change is to import [the `css` helper](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) from `styled-components`!

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
```

That will fix it.

I'd recommend reading [our documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs) so you're aware of the features the library has. It's not very long but it'll set you up for success. We'll also update the documentation to include the full import! ([reference issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components-website/issues/51))

Comment: Thank you very much. I had added the css as an import, but due to a unrelated JavaScript error, I was not able to make it work. Having said that, styled-components is well documented, works, makes componentization really work. It just rocks.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, glad you're liking it!